# ASP.NET Invalid Postback or callback argument on "asp:button" click with JQuery POST

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am learning how to use ajax with asp.NET and `jQuery`, and am trying to simulate a simple file editor in browser. So far I have a list of files being loaded using ajax and `jQuery` through WebMethods. When I try to duplicate that functionality for a button click in order to load the file, I get an exception for an invalid postback. I have tried numerous methods of linking the `jQuery` to the button and debugging the incoming values but it is getting late and I simply cannot seem to find the problem D:

My View:

```
<form id="textform" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectFile" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select a file..." Value="" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLoadFile" runat="server" Text="Load File" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="Save File" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
</div>
</form>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class WebEditor : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetFileList()
    {
        string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "\\Files";
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        foreach(string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(fileName);
        }

        return files;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string LoadFileContents(string fileName)
    {
        string fileContents = string.Empty;
        string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "\\Files\\" + fileName;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
        }

        return fileContents;
    }
}
```

FileEditor.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnLoadFile").on('click', LoadFile);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebEditor.aspx/GetFileList",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnFileListReceived,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});

function OnFileListReceived(response) {
    var files = response.d;
    var fileList = $("#ddlSelectFile");

    $(files).each(function (val, text) {
        fileList.append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
    });
}

});


function LoadFile() {
var selectedFile = $("#ddlSelectFile").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebEditor.aspx/GetFileList",
    data: JSON.stringify({ selectedFile: selectedFile }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnFileContentsReceived,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
}


function OnFileContentsReceived(response) {
    var fileContents = response.d;
}
```

The exception message that is thrown:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +9748914
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +64
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +457
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1833
```

Any advice/fixes to this problem would be wonderful.

Comment: In your button click, you seem to be calling the `"WebEditor.aspx/GetFileList"` web method which don't have any parameter but you are passing the parameter with `data: JSON.stringify({ selectedFile: selectedFile })` where your first call has no such parameter `data: '{}'`. Why do you need this?

Comment: You can look at my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: As per your comment, I have investigated this further and can see *3 issues* totally as listed down below.

Once all the *3 issues* fixed, I can check this working in the sample app I created.

So I hope this should work for you as well 100%.

**Issue 1**:

In your `LoadFile` function, I assume you should call `LoadFileContents` but you are calling `GetFileList` with a parameter `data: JSON.stringify({ selectedFile: selectedFile })` which shouldn't have any parameter defined in the code behind web method.

So you can change this to `WebEditor.aspx/LoadFileContents` as below.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebEditor.aspx/LoadFileContents"
        ....
});
```

**Issue 2**:

As the `WebMethod` has a parameter name as `fileName` at `public static string LoadFileContents(string fileName)`, the parameter name below should be same as this like,

```
data: JSON.stringify({ fileName: selectedFile })
```

**Issue 3**:

And finally, when the button `<asp:Button` renders on client side, it renders as "submit" button `type="submit"` and hence this is invoking a form submit which again ends with the above mentioned error. So to prevent this form submitting, you can add the below line,

```
function LoadFile(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ....
}
```

Hence, your final `function` becomes as below,

```
   function LoadFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedFile = $("#ddlSelectFile").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebEditor.aspx/LoadFileContents",
            data: JSON.stringify({ fileName: selectedFile }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnFileContentsReceived,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

And I render the file content in the textbox with below code,

```
    function OnFileContentsReceived(response) {
        var fileContents = response.d;
        $("#txtFileEditor").val(fileContents);
    }
```

Comment: This seemed so obvious it had to be the answer, it definitely was a problem that was solved but I still get the error.

Comment: It seems to be making it into the load file contents method and loading the data, but after the callback is complete, it fires off this error message again

Comment: Let me check this today

Comment: @KyleJensen Good news, all your issues got fixed. Please look at my above updated answer.

Comment: The first two I caught the next morning when I wasn't so tired but I didn't even think to use e.preventDefault in this case, been a while since I've used javascript. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Within your LoadFileContents Webmethod try the !Page.IsPostback solution (http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/ispostback.htm) :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string LoadFileContents(string fileName)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       string fileContents = string.Empty;
       string path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "\\Files\\" + fileName;

       if (File.Exists(path))
       {
          fileContents = File.ReadAllText(path);
       }
       return fileContents;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is WebMethods are static, so Page.IsPostBack isn't accessible